# how renew user access token without user relogin?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have a facebook app which posting on user's wall a quote every hours. the problem that's facebook deprecated offline_access permission and apply a new rules for access tokens (max 60 days) [look here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) .. 
so, I can not send my users any notifications about coming back and renew there access tokens .. the problem taht is there any way to renew these access tokens without user interaction !!

And is that means that each new registered user will need to login to my app again every 2 months to keep alive with my app ?

and what's the best **new** *way* to register a user to my app (hosted on a PHP website) ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I think if a users not returning to your app within 2 months they have no interest in the app therefore you should be posting anything else on there behalf, facebook doesnt like that, hence, why they took that out.. however there is a way, i remember running across it, i'll look around see what i can dig up.

Comment: I know that, but the main idea of my app is to register once and you'll have quotes on your wall everyday, so my users do not need to visit my app again. now I do not have any method to tell them back to my app. It'll be nice if you help me.

Comment: Did you figure out more on this topic?